# is this correct because label not get the value and indicates

Tags: java, label

String sm1 = combo2.getSelectedItem().toString();

```
  if("Software Engineering ".equals(sm1)){
       String s1 = txt1.getText();
      int t1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
      double avg;

      avg = t1/15*100;
      String finalanswer = Double.toString(avg);
      ans.setText(finalanswer);
```

o\is this correct because label not get the value and indicates

Comment: Be careful with your order of operations calculating `avg`. Right now you're doing integer division first, and then multiplying by 100. You probably want to multiply first, divide second so that it doesn't truncate too much.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really intend the trailing space in `"Software Engineering "`.?

Perhaps you should compare to `"Software Engineering"`:

```
if ("Software Engineering".equals(sm1)) {
```